# Have to reapply settings via PulseAudio control every time I restart for headphones to work

Tags: kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

When I installed Kubuntu 14.04 headphones didn't work. So I installed Pulseaudio Volume Control GUI app for KDE and I have to change where it says Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo to Headphones (unplugged) - which by the way, it's not unplugged - from Line out (pluggedin)

When I do this, the sound for my speakers still works, and also the sound of the headphones, which is what I want. But if I don't do this, the headphones don't work.

I tried all kinds of solutions online but nothing seems to work. Every time I restart headphones don't work.

This is a desktop

And my questions is, does anyone know how to solve this issue so that headphone is by default on every time when I restart? I don't know how to do this via the command line so hard to add as a script. And the help files for alsa/pulseaudio are SO convoluted and complicated.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]